# FB live API fails after successful app review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming, webrtc, live-video

I am using live-video API and it works fine in development mode.
I also created a app-review and it was successful.

Report from my dashboard.
[image]

After the review was completed I switched the app to live mode and started using the API again but I keep getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#10) To use live-video-api on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "Ez+RzDF2/zj"
    }
}
```

Not sure if anything should be done after the review was accepted.

Comment: You're positive you're using your production app ID, and not a test app ID?

Comment: @Brad Where's the prouction app id? Let me explain my case I have a single app on FB. I dont have test and production app. And no matter I switch my app from dev/live mode the app-id is the same on my header. Am I missing anything?

Comment: No, sounds like you have the right ID then.  :-(

Comment: @Brad, It turned out that I need to create a review for Live-video api to not just public_video.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  You should add that as an answer to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had to create a new review for `Live Video API` too. I was'nt aware that `FB-rtmp` needed both `publish_api` and `Live Video API`.

Refer to bug discussion [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/826527531079685/?disable_redirect=0)